# NPM repo missing file

Tags: ember.js, npm, ember-cli

I have a git repo for an Ember Addon:

> https://github.com/lifegadget/ui-responsive-toolbelt

It passes all unit tests. It has been published to npm as [ui-responsive-toolbelt](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ui-responsive-toolbelt). I have used **npm**'s "link" functionality to test locally that this "addon" (in Ember parlance) works fine in consuming application when included in the `package.json` file as a dependency.

Surprisingly, and I'm completely flummoxed on this, when **npm** installs this dependency into an Ember project directory it brings across a vast majority of the files without complaining. From NPM's perspective it appears to be a clean install. Unfortunately an addon depends heavily on it's "entry point" which is the [`index.js`](https://github.com/lifegadget/ui-responsive-toolbelt/blob/master/index.js) in the root directory of the repo. I have very clearly included this file in the repo but for some reason it is not being brough over!

I have tried this on two computers and three Ember projects and all have the same outcome. Please help!

---

the error message I get from Ember-CLI when I try to start the server with `ember serve` is:

> The package `ui-responsive-toolbelt` is not a properly formatted package, we have used a fallback lookup to resolve it at `/path/to/project/node_modules/ui-responsive-toolbelt`. This is generally caused by an addon not having a `main` entry point (or `index.js`).

This message is repeated twice and then I get:

> The `ui-responsive-toolbelt` addon could not be found at `/path/to/project/node_modules/ui-list/node_modules/ui-responsive-toolbelt`.

Comment: I just confirmed your report. Maybe you need to `npm publish` again?

Comment: What npm version are you using?

Comment: npm is version 2.8.3

Comment: @KevinBoucher yeah I have tried a few publishes to see if that would get things working but so far no luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. I confirmed that your repo looks fine
2. `npm install ui-responsive-toolbelt` does not download the index file

So the problem is that `npm publish` is not working properly. There is a bug filled for that. https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/5082

What you can do is publish again your addon using a recent npm version (or play with older versions) until you see that the index file is added too.

Comment: Ok, thanks for pointing me to this issue. Looking through the long list of 'victims' I found enough of a thread that I was able to fix this with the following change:  https://github.com/lifegadget/ui-responsive-toolbelt/commit/38c8c267045d15a699626bb7922a55c30f420a19